# Conditional Merging two data tables in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table 1 which has the following data as show in the below code:

```
data have(index=(date));
infile cards truncover expandtabs;
input TPMC  PWC PWSC $  Site    ET  $ Date : date9. Time $ DIAM $ PXMC  $ SF;
format date date9.;
cards;
7101    7101    US000521    1   Works1  08Nov2016   11:58   890,3       1
7102    7102    US000361    1   Works2  02Nov2016   13:01   878,1       1
7102    7102    UC000348    2   Works3  07Nov2016   18:22   877,3       1
7106    7106    UC00424 1   Works1  05Oct2016   9:43    890,4       1
7106    7106    UC00437 3   Works2  07Nov2016   18:23   877,1       1
7106    7106    UC309   4   Works3  07Nov2016   18:26   877,8       1
7107    7107    UC05327 1   Works1  06Oct2016   8:41    837     1
7107    7107    UC200   2   Works2  13Oct2016   12:53   890,55      1
7108    7108    UC000361    3   Works1  02Nov2016   13:01   878,1       1
7108    7108    UC00432 1   Works2  07Nov2016   18:25   877,8       1
7108    7108    UC106   2   Works3  03Oct2016   9:37    890,3       1
;
run;

data want;
 set have;
 array x{1} _temporary_;
array y{1} $ 40 _temporary_;
 x{1}=date;y{1}=TPMC;
 call missing(of _all_);
 TPMC=y{1};Time=0;
 do i=5 to 1 by -1;
   date=x{1}-i;output;
 end;
 set have point=_n_;output;
 call missing(of _all_);
 TPMC=y{1};Time=0;
 do i=1 to 5;
   date=x{1}+i;output;
 end;
 drop i;
 run;
```

and I have another table like the one below:

```
data have0001;
  input WPmeas $ Date :date8. Time :Time. T_Id $ ASN $ WC $ CWC T_Side M_No $ Yval $ XVal $;
  FORMAT DATE date8. Time HHMM.;
datalines;
1 19JAN16 12:19 20949 1 7604 US2301 R 1 -82140 2468
2 21JAN16 11:11 20949 1 7604 US2302 R 2 -81940 2466
3 01FEB16 16:13 20949 1 7604 US2303 R 3 -81739 2463
4 29MAR16 13:12 20949 1 7604 US2303 R 4 -81539 2459
5 13MAY16 14:11 20949 1 7604 US2304 R 5 -81339 2456
6 05OCT16 15:15 20949 1 7106 US2301 R 6 -82140 2468
7 07NOV16 16:18 20949 1 7106 US2302 R 7 -81940 2466
8 01FEB16 17:15 20949 1 7604 US2303 R 8 -81739 2463
9 29MAR16 18:17 20949 1 7604 US2303 R 9 -81539 2459
10 13MAY16 19:12 20949 1 7604 US2304 R 10 -81339 2456
;
run;
```

I am just trying to find out the ways to do the following:

1. select t1.PWSC = t2.CWC and t1.TPMC = t2.WC
2. select Dates from t1 (t1.Date) = t2.Date
3. select Time from t1 (t1.time) and only first value of time from t2.Time (i.e. if we sort Time in ascending order, the first will be 00:00, provided it is there otherwise whichever is first is picked up)

then

4. Merge the two datasets.

In other words what I am needing is to retrieve data from **t2** and merge with **t1** only when the dates are matching, the WC/TPMC and CWC/PWSC are matching. and Also, the time in t2 is the first observation in asc. order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot comment on your post to ask specifications. As I understand your question: You want to merge your tables "want" (=t2) and "have0001" (=t1). Duplicates with respect to key variables pwc cwc and date occure in "have0001" (=t1).

I assume that "have0001" (=t1) is the small table and sorting it while not cause too many problems. Then the following code merges the two tables using a hash object.

It procduces a table merge1 taking the first duplicate in t1 with the smallest time value. If you want duplicates to be merged with the same values from t2 several times and output them, there is also an example at the end of the code giving you a dataset merge2.

```
data have(index=(date));
infile cards truncover expandtabs;
input TPMC  PWC PWSC $ Site    ET  $ Date : date9. Time :Time. DIAM $ PXMC  $ SF;
format date date9.;
cards;
7101    7101    US2301    1   Works1  19JAN16   11:58   890,3       1
7102    7102    US2301    1   Works2  02Nov2016   13:01   878,1       1
7102    7102    UC000348    2   Works3  07Nov2016   18:22   877,3       1
7106    7106    UC00424 1   Works1  05Oct2016   9:43    890,4       1
7106    7106    UC00437 3   Works2  07Nov2016   18:23   877,1       1
7106    7106    UC309   4   Works3  07Nov2016   18:26   877,8       1
7107    7107    UC05327 1   Works1  06Oct2016   8:41    837     1
7107    7107    UC200   2   Works2  13Oct2016   12:53   890,55      1
7108    7108    UC000361    3   Works1  02Nov2016   13:01   878,1       1
7108    7108    UC00432 1   Works2  07Nov2016   18:25   877,8       1
7108    7108    UC106   2   Works3  03Oct2016   9:37    890,3       1
;
run;

data have0001;
  input WPmeas $ Date :date8. Time :Time. T_Id $ ASN $ WC CWC $ T_Side M_No $ Yval $ XVal $;
  FORMAT DATE date8. Time HHMM.;
datalines;
2 19JAN16 12:00 20949 1 7101 US2301 R 2 -81940 2466
1 19JAN16  11:58 20949 1 7101 US2301 R 1 -82140 2468
3 01FEB16 16:13 20949 1 7604 US2303 R 3 -81739 2463
4 29MAR16 13:12 20949 1 7604 US2303 R 4 -81539 2459
5 13MAY16 14:11 20949 1 7604 US2304 R 5 -81339 2456
6 05OCT16 15:15 20949 1 7106 US2301 R 6 -82140 2468
7 07NOV16 16:18 20949 1 7106 US2302 R 7 -81940 2466
8 01FEB16 17:15 20949 1 7604 US2303 R 8 -81739 2463
9 29MAR16 18:17 20949 1 7604 US2303 R 9 -81539 2459
10 13MAY16 19:12 20949 1 7604 US2304 R 10 -81339 2456
;
run;

data want;
 set have;
 array x{1} _temporary_;
array y{1} $ 40 _temporary_;
 x{1}=date;y{1}=TPMC;
 call missing(of _all_);
 TPMC=y{1};Time=0;
 do i=5 to 1 by -1;
   date=x{1}-i;output;
 end;
 set have point=_n_;output;
 call missing(of _all_);
 TPMC=y{1};Time=0;
 do i=1 to 5;
   date=x{1}+i;output;
 end;
 drop i;
 run;

proc sort data=have0001;
by WC CWC date time
run;

data merged1;
if 0 then set have0001;
if _N_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash hh(dataset:'have0001',ordered:'Y',multidata:'Y');
    hh.definekey('WC','CWC','date');
    hh.definedata(all:'Y');
    hh.definedone();
end;

do until (theend);
    set want (rename=(PWSC=CWC TPMC=WC)) end=theend;
    rc = hh.find();
    if rc=0 then output;
end;
run;

data merged2;
if 0 then set have0001;
if _N_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash hh(dataset:'have0001',ordered:'Y',multidata:'Y');
    hh.definekey('WC','CWC','date');
    hh.definedata(all:'Y');
    hh.definedone();
end;
do until (theend);
    set want (rename=(PWSC=CWC TPMC=WC)) end=theend;
    rc = hh.find();
    do while (rc = 0);
    output;
    rc = hh.find_next();
    end;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a [proc sql](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p12ohgh32ffm6un13s7l2d5p9c8y.htm) solution as your first two listed items can be a `JOIN` clause and last requirement can be a correlated aggregate [subquery](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm) in a `WHERE` clause:

```
proc sql;
  CREATE TABLE want AS
  SELECT t1.TPMC, t1.PWC, t1.PWSC, t1.Site, t1.ET, t1.Date AS t1Date, t1.Time AS t1Time, 
         t1.DIAM, t1.PXMC, t1.SF, t2.WPmeas, t2.Date AS t2Date, t2.Time AS t2Time, t2.T_Id, 
         t2.ASN, t2.WC, t2.CWC, t2.T_Side, t2.M_No, t2.Yval, t2.XVal
  FROM have t1
  INNER JOIN have0001 t2       
  ON t1.TPMC = t2.WC AND t1.PWSC = t2.CWC AND t1.Date = t2.Date
  WHERE t2.Time IN (SELECT MIN(sub.Time) 
                    FROM have0001 sub
                    WHERE sub.CWC = t2.CWC 
                    AND sub.Date = t2.Date);
quit;
```

*As seen, all columns are listed out instead of abbreviated `SELECT t1.*, t2.*` due to the repeated column names in both datasets: `Date` and `Time`. Otherwise, SAS drops the latter with a `WARNING`.*